# Convert image of dimension height,width,number of channels to n_masks, image_height, image_width

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I have an RGB image, it contains masks of different colors, each color represents a particular class.
I want to convert it into the format - `n_masks, image_height, image_width` where n_masks is number of masks present in the image. and each slice of the matrix along the 0th axis represents one binary mask.
So far, I have been able to convert it into the format of `image_height, image_width` where each array value represents which class it belongs to but I am kind of struck after it.
Below is my code to convert it into `image_height,image_width` format-

```
def mask_to_class(mask):
    target = torch.from_numpy(mask)
    h,w = target.shape[0],target.shape[1]
    masks = torch.empty(h, w, dtype=torch.long)
    colors = torch.unique(target.view(-1,target.size(2)),dim=0).numpy()
    target = target.permute(2, 0, 1).contiguous()
    mapping = {tuple(c): t for c, t in zip(colors.tolist(), range(len(colors)))}
    for k in mapping:
        idx = (target==torch.tensor(k, dtype=torch.uint8).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2))
        validx = (idx.sum(0) == 3) 
        masks[validx] = torch.tensor(mapping[k], dtype=torch.long)
    return masks
```

It converts an image of let's say format (512,512,3) to (512,512) where each pixel values represents the class it belongs to, but I don't have any idea how to proceed further.
P.S- I am coding it in `pytorch` but any approach involving `numpy` is also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you already have (512,512) mask. You can first use `mask.unique()` to get all classes pixel values. Then for each class value, `torch.where(mask==cls_val, torch.tensor(1), torch.tensor(0))` will return the mask of one certain class. In the end, you stack all outputs.

```py
mask = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],
                     [2,4,5],
                     [1,2,3]])
cls = mask.unique()
res = torch.stack([torch.where(mask==cls_val, torch.tensor(1), torch.tensor(0)) for cls_val in cls])

#tensor([[[1, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0],
#         [1, 0, 0]],
#
#        [[0, 1, 0],
#         [1, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0]],
#
#        [[0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1]],
#
#        [[0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 1, 0],
#         [0, 0, 0]],
#
#        [[0, 0, 0],
#         [0, 0, 1],
#         [0, 0, 0]]])
```